# Selenim driver for Chrome 116.x and Mac

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using Chrome Selenium in Phyton for almost two years and works great. When Chrome is updated I normally go to https://chromedriver.chromium.org/ download the right version, copy it in the path and everything continues working fine.

Since, chrome version 115.x the downloaded file name has changed and instead of 'chromedriver' now is 'Google Chrome for Testing.app'. I have changed the name referenced in python including the path and the extension but when trying to call webdriver.Chrome I obtained this error message:

`'Message: 'executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home'`

This is the source code that has been working fine until the last chrome version:

```
    def __init__(self, seleniumDriver):
        from selenium import webdriver

        try:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./../SeleniumDrivers/Google Chrome for Testing.app')
            self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
                "source": """
                Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
                  get: () => undefined
                })
              """
            })
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument("start-maximized")
            options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
            options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=seleniumDriver)

            self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
                "source": """
                        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
                          get: () => undefined
                        })
                      """
            })
            self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable", {})
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I am trying to uses the driver corresponding the last chrome version I have 116.x but instead of executing the driver and start scraping I received the indicated error message.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to run in a terminal: `chmod +x /path/to/chromedriver`

Comment: Thank you Gilles, I did it but still not working

Comment: The new version is not a binary but an "app" and within the package there is a file in "/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome for Testing" that is an "exe" terminal file. When executing it in the terminal chrome test opens fine but if I indicated that path in python program I receive the error "'Google Chrome for Testing' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
" as if the path could not be resolved

Comment: Solved: problem is that now you are allowed to download the whole Chrome, not only the driver, so I got confused and download Chrome.zip instead the regular chromedriver.ex